# How to differentiate click event between views in adapter?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with a custom view inflated for each items. This custom view contains only a favorite `ImageView`. I set the onclick in my holder class as follows:

```
class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private OnItemViewClickListener onItemViewClickListener;
    private OnFavoriteImageViewClickListener onFavoriteImageViewClickListener;
    private ImageView favoriteImageView;

    DataViewHolder(View itemView, OnItemViewClickListener onItemViewClickListener,
                    OnFavoriteImageViewClickListener onFavoriteImageViewClickListener) {
        super(itemView);
        this.onItemViewClickListener = onItemViewClickListener;
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        favoriteImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.favorite_image_view);
        this.onFavoriteImageViewClickListener = onFavoriteImageViewClickListener;
        favoriteImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    void bindData(Data data) {
        //Bind data to views
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        Data clickedData = getItem(position);
        onItemViewClickListener.onItemViewClick(clickedData);
        onFavoriteImageViewClickListener.onFavoriteImageViewClick(clickedData);
    }
}

public interface OnItemViewClickListener {
    void onItemViewClick(Data data);
}

public interface OnFavoriteImageViewClickListener {
    void onFavoriteImageViewClick(Data data);
}
```

As you can see, I once set the click listener on the entire view and once on the image view. The problem is that when I click the `ImageView` both click events are triggered, that one one the entire view and the second on the `ImageView`. Hot to stop the first one (on the entire view) and remain only the one the `ImageView`? Thanks!

Comment: If you only want the `ImageView` click listener remove your `OnItemViewClickListener`

Comment: @sanoJ I want to do separate action when click on the entire view, and separate action when clicked only on the `ImageVIew`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out which `View` was clicked by evaluating its `id` attribute, see also [View.getId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId()):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int position = getAdapterPosition();
    Data clickedData = getItem(position);
    int id = view.getId();
    if (id == R.id.favorite_image_view){
        onFavoriteImageViewClickListener.onFavoriteImageViewClick(clickedData)
    }
    else {   
        onItemViewClickListener.onItemViewClick(clickedData);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like below. Use two method definition in a single interface and set these methods to the `clickListeners` of the View and the ImageView respectively. Then implement those methods in the Activity your using to set the Adapter

```java
class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private dataViewClickListener dataViewClickListener;
    private ImageView favoriteImageView;

    DataViewHolder(View itemView, final dataViewClickListener dataViewClickListener) {
        super(itemView);
        this.dataViewClickListener = dataViewClickListener;
        favoriteImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.favorite_image_view);
    }

    void bindData(final Data data) {
        // Bind data to views
        // then add the listeners
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dataViewClickListener.onItemViewClick(data);
            }
        });
        favoriteImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dataViewClickListener.onFavoriteImageViewClick(data);
            }
        });
    }
}

public interface dataViewClickListener {
    void onItemViewClick(Data data);
    void onFavoriteImageViewClick(Data data);
}
```

You can find out more from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47347598/9263083)

Comment: It doesn't work, I have the same behavior. Have you test it, does it work?

Comment: Voted-up because you gave me the idea to have a single interface and not two. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using Id you can identify which view is clicked. You can find out which View was clicked by evaluating by its id attribute. You can also use switch of simple if condition to manage operations.

```
@Override public void onClick(View v) {
    Data clickedData = getItem(getAdapterPosition());
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.favorite_image_view:
             onFavoriteImageViewClickListener.onFavoriteImageViewClick(clickedData)
             break;
        // Add more case view id if needed
        default:
             onItemViewClickListener.onItemViewClick(clickedData);
      } 
  }
```