# How to implement two OnClickListener on two different views on RecyclerView kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I am working a RecyclerView item that has two views in it: a TextView and an ImagaView. I want to be able to click on both of them to cary out different functionalities.

How can I go about this

Here is my Adapter

```
class AddMeasurementAdapter(private val currentList:MutableList<DressMeasurementModel>, private val listener1: RecyclerClickListener, private val listener2: RecyclerClickListener): RecyclerView.Adapter<AddMeasurementAdapter.CardViewHolder>() {

    //inner class
    inner class CardViewHolder (itemView : View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener{
        val display:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.measurement_recyclerview_item)
        //Binding the data with the view
        fun  bind(dressMeasurementModel: DressMeasurementModel){
            display.text = "${dressMeasurementModel.measurementName} ${dressMeasurementModel.measurement}"

        }

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this@CardViewHolder)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            val position: Int = adapterPosition
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                listener1.onItemClick1(position, currentList)

            }

            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                listener2.onItemClick2(position, currentList)

            }

        }


    }


    //Creating view
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CardViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.measurement_fragment_recyclerview_items, parent, false)

        return CardViewHolder(view)
    }
    //Binding the view
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CardViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(currentList[position])
    }
    //Getting the item cout size
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return currentList.size
    }

}
```

Here is my interface

```
interface RecyclerClickListener {
    fun onItemClick1(position: Int, currentList: MutableList<DressMeasurementModel>)
    fun onItemClick2(position: Int, currentList: MutableList<DressMeasurementModel>)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle multiple layout clicks in recyclerView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698436/how-to-handle-multiple-layout-clicks-in-recyclerview-in-android)

Comment: I am not that good in java and I am  working with kotlin @Anand

Answer (score 2):

You can add a listener in createViewHolder such as

```
//Creating view
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CardViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.measurement_fragment_recyclerview_items, parent, false)
        view.textView.onClick{}
        view.image.onClick{}
        return CardViewHolder(view)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is the `Kotlin` version of the answer.

In your `bind` method of viewholder,

```
fun bind(dressMeasurementModel: DressMeasurementModel) {
    ...
    var position = adapterPosition

    display.setOnClickListener {
        listener.onTextClick(position)
    }

    image.setOnClickListener {
        listener.onImageClick(position)
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I later figured it So i want to share how i did it.

```
class AddMeasurementAdapter(
    private val currentList: MutableList<DressMeasurementModel>,
    private val listener1: RecyclerClickListener,
    private val listener2: RecyclerClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AddMeasurementAdapter.CardViewHolder>() {

    // inner class
    inner class CardViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val display: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.measurement_recyclerview_item)
        val delete: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.measurementment_recyclerview_item_delete_button)
//        Binding the data with the view
        fun bind(dressMeasurementModel: DressMeasurementModel) {
            display.text = "${dressMeasurementModel.measurementName} ${dressMeasurementModel.measurement}"
        }
    }

    // Creating view
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CardViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.measurement_fragment_recyclerview_items,
            parent,
            false
        )

        return CardViewHolder(view)
    }
    // Binding the view and attaching the listener
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CardViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(currentList[position])
        
        holder.display.setOnClickListener {
            listener1.onItemClickToEdit(holder.adapterPosition, currentList)
        }

        holder.delete.setOnClickListener {
            listener2.onItemClickToDelete(holder.adapterPosition, currentList)
        }
    }
    // Getting the item cout size
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return currentList.size
    }
}
```

When i assigned the onClickListener inside the `fun bind()`, the listener covered the the whole itemView layout and not the individual view inside the layout, hence only one click listener was achieved. The same thing applied inside the inner class.

Here is the interface

```
interface RecyclerClickListener {
    fun onItemClickToEdit(position: Int, currentList: MutableList<DressMeasurementModel>)
    fun onItemClickToDelete(position: Int, currentList: MutableList<DressMeasurementModel>)
}
```

By extending the interface in either activity of fragment, you have your onclickListener.

This article helped https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/